# jQuery chaining functions task

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, chaining

I'd like to use jQuery to build a series of six buttons with values A, B, C, 1, 2, 3. Each time the user clicks a button, its value is appended to a text field. However, the user must not be able to add two letters or two numbers in a row. Thus, if A, B, or C is pressed, only the numbers should work, and vice-versa.

Comment: Your question is really unclear, please edit it and explain more

Comment: This is not a `jQuery chaining question` but of `string concatenation`

Comment: No, I'm sorry I did not. What is your question? Do you already have some code, and what does it have to do with [chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)?

Comment: 6 buttons (3 letters and 3 numbers)
On each click it should display it in text box but shouldn't allow twice to submit number/letter. It's not string concatenation and I want 2 types of functions (1 for letters and 1 for numbers). Imagine it more like doing a calculator or so.

Sorry for briefed explanation but have more stuff to do so tried to keep it simple..

Comment: Tried to keep it simple? Telling us you want 6 characters concatenated (which, by the way, **IS** `string concatenation`), but never 2 of the same type in a row, without having any code available or what you have / haven't attempted is keeping it **too** simple, confusing and somewhat cryptic.

Comment: Not string concatenation, I don't want that since I work later in functions a bit with values (that numbers and letters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function createButton(target, val, fn) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.value = val;
    btn.onclick = function() {
        fn(val);
    };
    target.appendChild(btn);
}

var state = null,
    values = [];
function addLetter(l) {
    if (state == "letter") return false;
    state = "letter";
    values.push(l);
    update();
}
function addNumber(n) {
    if (state == "number") return false;
    state = "number";
    values.push(n);
    update();
}

createButton(inputs, "A", addLetter);
createButton(inputs, "B", addLetter);
createButton(inputs, "C", addLetter);
createButton(inputs, 1, addNumber);
createButton(inputs, 2, addNumber);
createButton(inputs, 3, addNumber);

function update() {
    // do something with values
}
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/n83ae/1/)

Comment: This is great. I think it would be even nicer if you set `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` on the buttons that can't be used.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks a lot! I though imagined something else but clearly that cannot be done but there's always another way like this ;)

Comment: @JamesA.Rosen: That's a different thing then. And it would be `.prop('dsiabled', true)`!